# VBA Code Does Not Copy Worksheet For the Second Time If I Add A Button To The Copied Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that copies the chosen page in the workbook, manipulates it in a desired way and creates a report on a new worksheet. The next thing I want to do is to add a close button to the newly created report sheet. However, when I do this and close the report sheet using the button, the next time I try to get the same report, it gives a subscript out of range error. Here is the code for copying the worksheet:

```
Sheets(UserForm1.ComboBox3.Value).Copy After:=Sheets("Sheet1")
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = UserForm1.ComboBox3.Value & UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value
```

And here is the code that adds the button:

```
    Set btn = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Buttons.Add(3, 3.75, 93, 16.5)
    btn.OnAction = "raporKapat"
    btn.Characters.Text = "Kapat"
```

And here is the "raporKapat" macro that it refers to:

```
Private Sub raporKapat()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveSheet.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
P.S. the program works flawlessly without the close button.

Comment: I think that begavior is because the reference in the combo box is not updated.If you close the sheet and open it again it will get a new adress pointer - eg the sheet value. As long as you do not ensure that the combobox know about the new things it will came with such a error.

Comment: I did not understand :)

Comment: there is no code for copying sheet here, just for 1.changing the name to value from a form, 2. adding button, 3.deleting sheet

Comment: Are you sure the line `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = UserForm1.ComboBox3.Value & UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value` copies your sheet? Because that is most certainly not what it says it does.

Comment: Sorry guys that's my bad. Here is the code: `Sheets(UserForm1.ComboBox3.Value).Copy After:=Sheets("Sheet1")`
       
       `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = UserForm1.ComboBox3.Value & UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value`

Comment: Please add the code to your question, not as a comment. That said, with the code in your comment, you are coping a sheet and inserting it right after `Sheet1` and then renaming the last worksheet in your workbook.

Comment: Yes, Sheet1 is my last sheet, so I copy and paste a sheet right after it and then rename the sheet I have just copied.

Comment: Are you sure the line Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = UserForm1.ComboBox3.Value & UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value copies your sheet? It does not , it just copy the sheet handle or so called pointer pointer. To copy a sheet way more work is needed. Nad if you delete this "copy" or the original - there IS NO SHEET ANYMORE ! So you have to reload or create it again. and by this you will get a new sheet pointer or handle... Ive answered how to copy whole sheets or workbooks here. This will hopefully also get a idea how to close or destroy a sheet...

Comment: Thank you Thomas. But that is not the problem, if I remove the part that adds the button to the copied sheet, the code works perfectly. I think that there is something wrong with the part of the code that adds the button or the macro that I associate it to. (Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = UserForm1.ComboBox3.Value & UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value  does not copy my sheet; I edited that in the question)

Comment: I kind of solved the problem. I used to show UserForm1 whenever Sheet1 was activated. I disabled this and added a button to show UserForm1. I do not know why but it works perfectly fine now.